# Origin of equation $E = -p_{\mu}u_O^{\mu}$ in Relativity

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, relativity, observers

Well, basically as the title says, I have found the equation $$E = -p_{\mu}u_O^{\mu},$$ with $E$ energy, $p$ the 4-momentum of a particle and $u_O$ the velocity of an observer. I have found it in texts of General Relativity, but I don't remember it from Special Relativity.

Do you know the origin or where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $4$-velocity is a timelike vector, that means that you can always find a reference frame where it can be written in this form $u^\mu=(u^0,0,0,0)$ ; therefore $p_\mu u^\mu= p_0 u^0$ . Now take the $(-+++)$ signature, the 4-velocity $u$ is normalized to $-1$ and therefore $u^0=+1$ and $p_0=-p^0$ . Then in the end you get $$-p_\mu u^\mu= -p_0 u^0 = - (-p^0) =p^0= E$$

Now if you want you can try to generalize it in the general relativistc case as exercise.

Edit: sorry for the many edits but I had a few sign wrong when I've rewritten the answer using the metric you use.

Comment: +1: Just a minor comment: the book that OP is using seems to have the $-+++$ signature.

Comment: @DvijMankad you're right I should edit

Comment: Thx. The GR generalization would be the step $p_0 = g_{00}p^0$, where $g_{00}$ can be certainly more complex than just -1. Right?

Comment: @David Well you could simply use the correspondence principle ( substitute the minkowski metric $\eta$ with a general metric $g$) and that's it, since $p_\mu u^\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu}p^\mu u^\nu$.